# Impossible to update UI because can not delete widgets

Tags: pyqt4, pyside

I am creating an application with a dynamic user interface meaning that widgets should appear and vanish depending on data in a database. The code is listed below.

The data part is going alright, the update of UI not.

I create dynamically a widget within a QTabWidget. This widget (being a class) contains 3 widget: 2 listWidgets and a pushbutton. Deleting or calling the destroy-method, with or without the widget.update or widget.repaint is not successfull.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
class ImEntityWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, widgetParent, entityclass, x, y, width, height):
        self.widgetParent = widgetParent
        self.entityclass = entityclass

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.focusItem = session.query(Entity).filter(
                         Entity.parent_vpu_id == VpuFocus.Id).filter(
                         Entity.Class == self.entityclass).first()

        self.listWidgetHigher = QListWidget(self.widgetParent)
        self.listWidgetHigher.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
                                          self.x, self.y, self.width, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.listWidgetHigher.setFont(font)
        self.listWidgetHigher.setObjectName("listWidgetHigher" +
                                            str(self.entityclass.name))

        # Entity in focus pushbutton widget
        self.listWidget_pb = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widgetParent)
        self.listWidget_pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
                                       self.x, self.y + 25, self.width, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(7)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.listWidget_pb.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget_pb.setObjectName("pushButton" + str(self.entityclass.name))

        # Lower recursion entity widget
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self.widgetParent)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
                        self.x, self.y + 50, self.width, self.height - 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget" + str(self.entityclass.name))

        # set button context menu policy
        self.listWidget_pb.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.listWidget_pb.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
                                                    self.listWidget_pbCtxMenu)
        self.listWidget_pb.connect(self.listWidget_pb,
                SIGNAL("activated(QModelIndex)"), self.focusHigherRecursion)
        self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.doubleClick)


#Using the widget class
self.entWidget = ImEntityWidget(
              self.tabPrimaryProcesses, entityclass,
              wX, wY, wWidth, wHeight)
self.entityWidgets.append(self.entWidget)



# Trying to delete the widgets
for self.widget in self.entityWidgets:
    #del self.widget.listWidgetHigher
    #del self.widget.listWidget_pb
    #del self.widget.listWidget
    #self.tabPrimaryProcesses.update()
    self.widget.listWidgetHigher.destroy(destroyWindow=True)
    self.widget.listWidget_pb.destroy(destroyWindow=True)
    self.widget.listWidget.destroy(destroyWindow=True)
```

Comment: I ran into this problem last night.  I solved it by taking the container widget, `QTabWidget` in this case if I understand correctly, and setting its parent to `None`.  This will remove the `QTabWidget`.  Now recreate `QTableWidget` replacing it in the same location.  Now populate as normal.  I can give a better answer if you give a working sample code of what it is exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff is Right, to delete a Widget you should do try:

```
self.widget.listWidgetHigher.setParent(None)
self.widget.listWidget_pb.setParent(None)
self.widget.listWidget.setParent(None)
```